# For loop asterisk and plus sign (Rectangle form)

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, ascii-art

I want to make a program where the user inputs the height and width of the rectangle but using `*` and `+` alternatively. Here is my code:

```java
class Parallelogram {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner x = new Scanner(System.in);
        int w;
        int h;

        System.out.print("Enter the Width ");
        w = x.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter the height ");
        h = x.nextInt();

        for (int i = 0; i < h; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < w; j++) {
                System.out.print("*");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
MY PROGRAM :                   What i want my program to look
Enter width : 4                 Enter width : 4
Enter height : 5                Enter height : 5
****                            ****
****                            ++++
****                            ****
****                            ++++
****                            ****
```

Comment: you can use `if (i%2 == 0) print asterix else print plus `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a modulo in your for loop.

This code will do the trick for you:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner x = new Scanner(System.in);
    int w;
    int h;
    System.out.print("Enter the Width ");
    w = x.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Enter the height ");
    h = x.nextInt();
    for (int i = 0; i < h; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < w; j++) {
            if (i % 2 == 0) {
                System.out.print("*");
            } else {
                System.out.print("+");
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```